# error using method createStatment()

Tags: java, mysql, sql

i get error    when trying to create a simple table. here is my code thanks for the help
it says cannot find symbol...

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.Connection;

public class test1 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"); //Load the driver
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/data", "root", "test"); //Connect

            conn.createStatment().execute("Create TABLE 'Quiz1' ("+"'eventID' int(64),"+"'startTime' int(64)."+"UNIQUE('eventID'))");

            conn.createStatement().execute(" LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\Legyptiano\\Downloads\\quiz1.txt' INTO TABLE Quiz1"
                + "LINES TERMINATED BY '\\N'");

            conn.close();
        }
        catch (Exception err) { }
    }
}
```

The error I receive is:

```
C:\Users\Legyptiano\Documents\test1.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    conn.createStatment().execute("Create TABLE 'Quiz1' ("+"'eventID' int(64),"+"'startTime' int(64)."+"UNIQUE('eventID'))");
                ^

    symbol:   method createStatment()
    location: variable conn of type Connection
1 error
```

Comment: neither table names nor column names can be quoted with single quotes. If you quote them, use backticks.

Comment: Look very carefully at the symbol that can't be found. `createStatment`. Now look very carefully at the documentation for `Connection`, which will show `createStatement()`.

Comment: dammm i feel like a fool thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think, conn does not get assigned proper value in your code.

Check parameters passed to getConnection , the url should be in the following  form

url - a database url of the form jdbc:subprotocol:subname

Also make sure you have right username and password passed in the getConnection.

More information is found here 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html